# Optimizing Subqueries Including Functions and Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, query-optimization, query-performance

I currently have something along these lines:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.Something1, M.Something2, D1.Date, D2.Date, D3.Date
FROM MasterTable M
    LEFT JOIN DateTable1 D1
    LEFT JOIN DateTable2 D2
    LEFT JOIN DateTable3 D3
WHERE (D1.Date = (SELECT MAX(A.Date) FROM DateTable1 A WHERE A.MasterID = M.ID)
    OR D1.Date IS NULL)
AND (D2.Date = (SELECT MAX(B.Date) FROM DateTable2 B WHERE B.MasterID = M.ID)
    OR D2.Date IS NULL)
AND (D3.Date = (SELECT MAX(C.Date) FROM DateTable3 C WHERE C.MasterID = M.ID)
    OR D3.Date IS NULL)
```

This works fine and gives the right results, but it is rather slow. (There are also more joins and more 'somethings', but I do not believe they are relevant here.)

In my search for improving this query I found something along the lines of this in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (D1.Date, D2.Date, D3.Date) = (
    SELECT D1.Date...
    FROM DateTable1...
```

I don't know that I found something quite as complex as what I was trying for, but the general gist is that I was thinking I could grab all 3 of the dates in a single subquery. I tried something like:

```
WHERE (D1.Date, D2.Date, D3.Date) = (
    SELECT MAX(A.Date), MAX(B.Date), MAX(C.Date)
    FROM DateTable1 A, DateTable2 B, DateTable3 C
    WHERE... all the ids match
```

but that wouldn't run for me.

So, if nothing else, is there a way to better optimize that first query? Can I narrow it down to a single subquery? Is there another way I might be able to increase the performance?

Thanks

Comment: That tuple syntax works in oracle, but not sql server. Maybe the [OVER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause of the MAX function could help here.

Comment: Please share the table structure, sample data and the indexes on the tables if any. Without those most perf tuning suggestions are speculation.

Comment: How does it work fine if you have a wrong query? Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' for example

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your query is slow because you are getting a cartesian product of dates for each master id.  Try using this version:

```
SELECT M.ID, M.Something1, M.Something2, D1.Date, D2.Date, D3.Date
FROM MasterTable M LEFT JOIN
     (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by masterid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from DateTable1 d
     ) D1
     on d1.masterid = m.id and d1.seqnum = 1 left join
     (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by masterid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from DateTable2 d
     ) D2
     on d2.masterid = m.id and d2.seqnum = 1 left join
     (select d.*, row_number() over (partition by masterid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from DateTable3 d
     ) d3
     on d3.masterid = m.id and d3.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This and mark if helpful

```
SELECT M.ID, M.Something1, M.Something2, (SELECT MAX(A.Date) FROM DateTable1 A WHERE A.MasterID = M.ID) as 'D1Date',(SELECT MAX(B.Date) FROM DateTable2 B WHERE B.MasterID = M.ID) as 'D2Date', (SELECT MAX(C.Date) FROM DateTable3 C WHERE C.MasterID = M.ID) as 'D3Date' FROM MasterTable M
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using APPLY.

```
SELECT M.ID
    , M.Something1
    , M.Something2
    , D1.Date
    , D2.Date
    , D3.Date
FROM MasterTable M
cross apply
(
    select MAX(d.date) as Date
    from DateTable1 d
    where d.masterid = m.id
) d1
cross apply
(
    select MAX(d.date) as Date
    from DateTable2 d
    where d.masterid = m.id
) d2
cross apply
(
    select MAX(d.date) as Date
    from DateTable3 d
    where d.masterid = m.id
) d3
```